# C++ Module Partition Include Statements

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I have the following two files:

```
//building.cpp

export module building;
export import building:apartment;
```

```
//apartment.cpp

module;
#include<iomanip>
export module building:apartment;

void test(){
   std::streambuf* buf;
   std::ostream os(buf);
   os<<std::setw(17);
}
```

Using GCC11, I do

```
$ g++ -c apartment.cpp -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts
$ g++ -c building.cpp -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts
```

this code does not compile (internal compiler error). However, if I include iomanip into apartment.cpp and building.cpp I receive no errors. I remember a similar situation with the MSVC compiler. What am I doing wrong? Should the same include statements be included in the module file and its partition?

Comment: shouldn't module source have different extension?

Comment: @MarekR I think that only applies to MSVC (`.ixx`), but I'm not entirely sure. I haven't really used modules yet.

Comment: [This says](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-modules) clang has own extension too.

Comment: @MarekR It doesn't have to. In its tests, GCC simply use `.cpp` for everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation issue. You should search if the report does exist and write a report if there isn't.